# Mongodump cause mongodb to crash?

Tags: mongodb, mongodump

Running backups on a Mongo Replica set - 1 primary, 1 secondary, 1 arbitrar. Had a instance where all three stopped talking to one another and all went to secondary.

I ran a backup against the the Replica set with Mongodump. Would that cause the DB's to switch? Is there harm in running mongodump against a running production system on the Primary?

Comment: you need to take a look at the log files to see exactly what happened, but to answer your question, there should be no switch in which server is the primary and there is no harm in running mongodump in prod against a primary.

Comment: Thank you...yea the log files aren't saying much.  only that the instances can not see the other instances.  They are all online but not talking to each other.

Comment: so there are failed connection messages?  can you telnet from one machine to another into 27017 ports?  The reason they all went to secondary is because they cant see each other, not because of mongodump. What happens if you were to bring secondaries down and bring them back up?